# Storyboard file missing

Tags: xcode4

I'm new to xCode 4 and have playing with storyboards for most of the day. I was making an edit to one of the segue's and didn't realize that the entire file was selected, not just the arrow on the right side. This deleted my ENTIRE storyboard, which usually isn't a big deal as it's either still in the folder if i only deleted the reference, or in the trash if the file was actually deleted.

Strangely, it's in neither. I created a storyboard to test this out and sure enough, xCode warns "this can not be undone"....and it's gone. No where in finder or the trash bin.

Now, the weirdest part. My application is still running fine. I can't make any edits obviously as i can't bring it up, but xCode is still running fine. I've reset my computer and done everything else to clear it out but i can't my storyboard nor find it anywhere!

any help would be greatly appreciated...

jason

Comment: Also a bit more information. Here's a screenshot of xCode, notice the iPhone storyboard: https://skitch.com/jasonpurdy/gd823/xcode

Comment: And here's finder....nothing...https://skitch.com/jasonpurdy/gd826/eplrc-ios

Comment: I know that i can go into the plist and edit there for a new one, but i'd really like to not have to start froms scratch.

Comment: well, no answers unfortunately so i've just gone and redid the entire storyboard. It's much this time of course, but word to the wise! don't delete your storyboard or you'll lose it forever!!!

Answer (score 3):

This happened to me as well - very alarming!  However I searched for "storyboard" using SearchLight on the desktop.  This found the file as the top hit!  I was then able to track its location to a folder called **en.lproj** within the project folder and use File > Add to bring this folder back in.

Everything seemed fined except I had a problem every time I tried to delete the same image that caused the problem in the first place.  The image was just sitting in a viewcontroller as a background image and each time I deleted it the whole storyboard vanished (temporarily).

So, I simply removed this viewcontroller altogether and created a new one and that worked.  Much better than recreating the whole storyboard!